# What should I think about before ordering a poster print?

Tags: posters, digital-printing

I have constructed a Mandelbrot image using my own small python script. I am toying with the idea of taking it to a shop to have it printed on a 50x70cm poster to hang on the wall.

I know nothing of printing, and would like to not ruin the result *too* much in my ignorance.

Below is the picture I've made (it's somewhat low resolution here because of file size limitations; as it is digitally constructed, naturally I can make it in any resolution I want, and I suppose that when I get that far, I'll look at the prices for 150 vs 300 vs 600 ppi to see if I care enough to pay for it).

> [image]

I like that it is mostly black, and the I like the (almost) monochrome blue. I am somewhat satisfied with the level of banding (always an issue with dark colors). I like the colors as I see them on my screen. I think I like the off-center composition, although I might move the motive a *little* bit to the left.

However, I am uncertain how much of it translates to a poster. Should the curve be made thicker, or brighter, or both? I am afraid that especially the small details (all the lightning-like branching, and the smaller copies of the bulb) may become nearly invisible, but on the other hand, turning them up will probably give me banding elsewhere.

And what can I expect for the color? Heck, the colors looks different between my image viewer and my internet browser; the browser shows a clear blue, while my image viewer shows a more purple color. I have no idea what a poster printer might do.

Comment: Print a small proof first

Comment: Is this to be a one-off poster? (Only 1 printed). Are you looking at a run of multiple posters via a commercial printer? That amount of black coverage is *not* easily maintained in a run, and for a one-off can be hit or miss.. the problems are far *less* about the blue and are more about the overwhelming amount of black. You'd be better of screen printing blue on a black substrate. However, screen printing can be problematic for minute details.

Comment: @Scott Yeah, it's a one-off. (First I thought you were asking whether you were ever going to see me on this forum again. Synonyms are harsh some times.)

Comment: For a one off.. just take a PDF to your local copy shop. Chances are they have a very similar digital printer as would be used for any online vendor. You aren't going to get "commercial" quality, but you can still get a decent print for a one-off. And costs should be quite minimal, so running it 2 or 3 times with some adjustments shouldn't be too costly. Of course, that all depends on how important it is to you. -- And no.. :) You're very welcome here. 'One-off' is a common term for a 1 print. :)